# WeakReference getter returns null

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, viewmodel

I use MVVM architecture, but at one point I pass clicklistener into ViewModel. I do it in Fragment `onCreate` - i pass listener to ViewModel and wrap it in WeakReference object and store in ViewModel as a field.

```
private var weakRefListener: WeakReference<ClickListener>? = null
private val listenerViewModel = object : ClickListener {
    override fun onClicked(id: Long) {
        weakRefListener?.get()?.onClicked(id)
    }
}

/* called in Fragment */
fun setClickListener(clickListener: ClickListener) {
    weakRefListener = WeakReference(clickListener)
}
```

The reason why I do it - I have UI elements which are represented as data classes and I want to preserve them after screen rotation.

ViewModel has objects which need this clicklistener and they reference `listenerViewModel`. Unfortunately, I have observed undeterministic behaviour - sometimes `weakRefListener?.get()` returns `null` and I cannot predict when. This leads to bad User Experience as click does not work.

Question: 
- why does this happen?
- what is a better way to organize the code?

Comment: You got exactly the behavior you requested when you used `WeakReference`. Maybe you _don't_ want to use it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik but I have heard that it is not a good practice to have a strong reference to Views like Fragment or Activities.

Comment: OK, but why are you surprised at seeing exactly the behavior you requested? You seem to have your cake and eat it, too. If you could always get a non-null reference, that would make it a strong reference.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik i think I wanted to "fix" bad architecture by this hack. It was recommented by a colleague :( ideally, View should not pass View-related objects to lower layers. do you agree?

Comment: The "fix" consists exactly of getting a `null` when the object is GC'd. The "bad architecture" moment occurs when you require it to be non-null all the time.